# Incoherent results on Oracle Spatial Query with SDO_CONTAINS

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle11gr2, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

If I run the following query:

```
select zona
 , fid
 , count(*)
from geo_bcn_zones z join geo_bcn_illes i 
  on SDO_CONTAINS(z.geometria, i.geometria) = 'TRUE'
where zona='z01'and fid = 53
group by zona, fid
```

I got the following results:

```
 zona   fid count(*)
 z01    53  34
```

But if I run this other:

```
select zona
     , fid
     , count(*)
from geo_bcn_zones z
join geo_bcn_illes i 
on SDO_CONTAINS(z.geometria, i.geometria) = 'TRUE'
where zona='z01'
group by zona, fid
having fid = 53
```

The results are incoherent:

```
 zona   fid count(*)
 z01    53  10
```

Any suggestion?

I'm runnig `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: Hard to say anything. Could be invalid data (like wrongly oriented polygons). Impossible to say without the actual data. Maybe show the query plans for both executions and that will give a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is a bug somewhere. If I run:

```
select zona, fid, count(*)
from geo_bcn_zones z, geo_bcn_illes i 
where sdo_contains(z.geometria, i.geometria) = 'TRUE'
and zona = 'z01' and fid = '53'
group by zona, fid
```

The results are:

```
zona fid count(*)
z01 53  10
```

If I add a hit to avoid the index:

```
select /*+NO_INDEX(z, idx_geo_bcn_zones) */  zona, fid, count(*)
from geo_bcn_zones z, geo_bcn_illes i 
where sdo_contains(z.geometria, i.geometria) = 'TRUE'
and zona = 'z01' and fid = '53'
group by zona, fid
```

There results are correct:

```
zona fid count(*)
z01 53  34
```

:-(